# How to deal with error when mails are read

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap

The script is first doing it job

- find the message with specific subject
- send a message to the sender
- copy the message to folder 'answered'
- delete the message
- sleep for 1min and repeat

```
mail.select()
status, messages = mail.select("INBOX")
n = int(str(messages[0], 'utf-8'))
messages = int(messages[0])
for i in range(messages, messages-n,-1):
    res, msg = mail.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            Sub, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("Subject"))[0]    # Error is about this line
                Sub=Sub.decode((encoding))
            if Sub == pat:
                fro, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
                if isinstance(fro, bytes):
                    fro = fro.decode(encoding)
                # if s == 0:
                #     time.sleep(60)
                #     mai_load(1)

                print("From:", fro)
                send_mail(fro)
                mail.copy(str(i), 'praca')
                mail.store(str(i), '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')

            print("=" * 100)
            time.sleep(60)
            mai_load(0)
```

And here is the problem, messages are mark as read and when the scripts connects again I'm receiving an error:

```
line 99, in mai_load
    Sub, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("Subject"))[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/header.py", line 80, in decode_header
    if not ecre.search(header):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: What does `msg.get("Subject")` return? Apparently it is not a string or bytes-like object, as expected.

Comment: @mkrieger1 If message is unread it it returns correctly the Subject (email Title). The problem occur only if message is marked as READ.

Comment: I can't duplicate this.  Can you print `msg` or `msg._headers` after fetching and see if they look normal?

Answer (score 0):

Try my lib: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND, MailMessageFlags


with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:

    # get list of email senders from INBOX folder
    senders = [msg.from_ for msg in mailbox.fetch()]

    # FLAG unseen messages in current folder (INBOX) as Flagged
    mailbox.flag(mailbox.fetch(AND(seen=False)), [MailMessageFlags.FLAGGED], True)
```